# My Windows Forms Application is still running as task after closing

Tags: c#, windows, forms, process

I have build a C# Windows Forms Application with Visual Studio 2010.

Run and close application is done successfully within a short time.
The process is not running in Task-Manager. As well the debugging process close. No problem occurs.

But if the Application is running a while the program does not close and still leave running in Task-Manager
(I just open the apllication and do nothing else, just wait few hours to reproduce the problem).
In Debug mode i have to click on STOP DEBUGGING button to end process.

What can i do to find the rootcause?

Comment: What does your application do?

Comment: It's just waiting for user input and afterwards get data from a DataContext instance.

Comment: Have you tried pressing pause on the debugger? That might pause on the statement still keeping the program open.

Comment: Yes i have and get the messages: No Source Available & No disassembly available.

Comment: You should post your code.  You say that it's "just waiting for user input" - if that is true, why would you expect the code to finish?

If you cannot post your code, you will have to debug it by stepping through it, and seeing where it may be getting held up.

Comment: Sometimes the user clicks the close (X) button. Thereby the form will close but program is still running in Task-Manager. I am using mutex to prevent more than one instance and the application tells me that another app instance is running. In debug mode i have set the breakpoint in "static void Main()" method within Program.cs file and stepping throug it till the end without any problem. But if the app was running for some hours it will not close porperly.

Comment: @Mrko have you tried this code "System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();" in your form's FormClosing or FormClosed events?

Answer (score 2):

A process ends after all of the foreground threads stop.

In a typical Winforms application, there's one main foreground thread - the UI thread. This stops after the main form (the one used in `Application.Run`) is closed. Check what your `Main` method is doing afterwards, or just put a breakpoint there to see if the thread successfuly

You might also have some foreground worker thread if you're doing multi-threading. It's your responsibility to ensure they're all stopped. The tricky part is that some of the classes you're using might spin up such threads on their own, without you knowing about it. The first thing to keep in mind is that any object you create that implements `IDisposable` should actually be disposed. This might take care of the issue. One example that often causes trouble is `System.Threading.Timer` (or `System.Timers.Timer`) - if you don't `Dispose` it, it will keep your application running indefinitely.

To investigate the problem, you can use the thread list in Visual Studio's debugger (Debug -> Windows -> Threads). Run the application, wait as long as needed, close the form and then pause the debugger. The thread list will show all the managed threads in the process. Look at the location on the threads that are running - double-clicking a thread will switch your debugger view to that thread, and you can then see the call stack. This might give you some insight about where that thread came from, and what code it's currently executing (i.e. why it is stuck). You'll probably see a wait there somewhere (unless it's actually doing CPU work); just look at the call stack (Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack) and look for something to identify.

If you checked all the threads, and you can't see anything suspicious in the call stacks, you might have to do a bit of configuration in the debugger. There's two main things you can try - first, in the call stack window, right click and select "Show external code". If that doesn't help, you might have to disable Just My Code (Options -> Debugger), and enable symbol loading for the modules involved. This is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If the process is still pending that means you are not disposing your resources properly.

Using `Application.Exit()` or asking the system to do it `Environment.Exit(0)` may be logged in the system as an error occurred and you are better to know how to properly close a process than relied on `Application.Exit()`, if you want to close a thread of your app you have to know how to collect those garbage.

You can re-implement the `Dispose` method to Dispose services, sockets, streams, almost everything that has a `.Dispose` available.

```cs
 public class MyClass: IMyClass, IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;
        // ...
```

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

```cs
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_disposed) return;

    if (disposing)
    {
        // dispose your stuff you created in this class
        // do the same for other classes

        // some examples
        /*
        _webClient.Dispose();
        _connector.DataAvailable -= ConnectorHasDataComing
        _socket.Dispose();
        _timer.Dispose();
        _taskLogs.ForEach(x => {
            x.Token.Cancel();
            x.Task.Wait();
            x.Task.Dispose();
        });
        */
    }

    // dispose native events

    _disposed = true;
}
```

If you use `System.Threading.Thread` or `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` or `System.IO.MemoryStream` (or other kind of Stream - Writer/Reader), and others that requires a `CancellationTokenSource`. If you created the ressource in the class when you are disposing the class, use the `Token.Cancel()` method to let it know its parent is being disposed and `.Wait()` for it before calling `.Dispose()`

```
public async Task Run(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    // ...
    while (Running) {
        if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) return;
        // ....
    }

    // ....
    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(tempFile))
    {
         reader.Position = 0;
         await reader.CopyToAsync(fileWriter,81920, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

I found my issue using the Diagnostic Tools when my Debug was still pending on something after closing the app.

[image]

If you use CPU Usage you can click on `Break All` and it set a breakpoint.
You can then see profiler and find what are your top functions, you might find out that your form is disposed but you have a Thread or Task that invokes fields on your form.

[image]

For my case, I was using a filewriter and I implemented IDisposable in that class but it sometimes was about or actual doing a transfer of data between a filereader and itself using `.copyTo` so it was pending without throwing an exception.

[image]

After clicking on one the events, click on `Go to Source code` and place a breakpoint, you may see events that your code is stocked on.

Otherwise, you can use in the same tool the tab `Memory Usage` to take a snapshot and look at the Heap and Objects diff or the tab `CPU Usage` and look at a recorded Profile. If find my `copyTo` issue that way.

You can also run your app with `Throw on all exceptions`
[image]

Comment: I forgot to put a using() statement around my MemoryStream, so thanks for this comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your project contains more than 1 form than you should go to the events of the last form and double click on "FormClosed" event. After this action sends you to the code, write between the brackets:

```
 Application.Exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
     `Environment.Exit(0);`
 instead.